# Sun OS 5.10: Bash: Colors and Directory Listings

Tags: bash, putty, sunos

I'm on a Windows XP box.   I'm using putty 0.60 to access a unix account on a server running SunOS 5.10.  In my .profile file I have the command "bash" to put me into that shell upon logging in.

I know with Linux there are options to display files and directories in different colors when I issue the command "ls".

Can the same thing be set up for bash running in SunOS 5.10 ?

Thanks much in advance for any information.

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i understand it, the solaris version of `ls` (which you get by default in SunOS 5.10) does not support colored output.  you'd have to install the gnu version of `ls`, which is included in the coreutils package.

rather than explain the process of installing the package, i'll direct you to this link instead:
http://tille.garrels.be/training/solaris/colorls.php

if you can't install packages on that server, you may be out of luck.  hth

Comment: Yep. Getting the network crew to install it is not an option, but thanks for the fast answer about it not being doable in my situation.